# how to use subflow in spring integraion

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on project where we have used spring integration. And we have may flow which eventually create a full flow of the system.
Now, we needs to create a main flow which have all abstract component which internally call the sub flow. I found spring integration flow project for create a subflow. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow/tree/master.

But while I try to find out latest jar I found which is build on 2015 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-flow). Now I am confused that do we have to use this project or some other approach spring integration build which needs to use.

```
e.x:
we have 3 flow file.
1) prepare-file.xml
2) prepare-database.xml
3) enrich-object.xml
which eventually call like prepare-file.xml-->prepare-database.xml-->enrich-object.xml
```

Now, we like to create a file which is master-flow.xml which shows all component in diagram very high level.

Thanks,
Nishit C.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that project hasn't have enough interest in community for a while. And now when most people step aside from XML configuration in favor of Java & Annotation configuration with Spring Boot on top, such a project doesn't have its attractiveness any more.

On the other hand we provide a Java DSL for Spring Integration flows several years already: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#java-dsl

I would say its `IntegrationFlow` definitions with the sub-flow functionality may server for your requirements.

I understand that this might not be an answer you are looking for, but at least this one should be as some food to  think about.

Comment: Thank you @Artem, does this also says that SI is now more focused on java-dsl and we may dont have update for xml configuration ? One of there reason we like to create main flow out of sub flow is my Architect like to see the SI flow diagram. can java-dsl can give me SI flow diagram how xml is providing ? can you please provide your input in this.

Comment: No, XML configuration is not deprecated, but Java DSL has more attraction with community as long as I know. The Java DSL is nothing more than syntax sugar over existing components which are used in XML as well. Not sure what you use to make diagrams, but any Spring Integration flows can be visualized by the result of the Integration `Graph`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#integration-graph. This is just out of our scope to support a visual part in our project.